# AWS IP Forwarding

Tags: ip, amazon-web-services, forwarding

I have an Elastic IP on AWS that I want to forward to a Public IP outside of AWS.

Any ideas how I could accomplish this?

Comment: You'd need to have na instance running at the AWS IP, but you could proxy everything to the second IP via iptables. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595575/iptables-configuration-for-transparent-proxy Not sure why you wouldn't want to just use the real public IP, though.

Answer (score 1):

as @ceejayoz mentioned, iptables can do the redirection on layer 3/4, however, if you are serving up a tcp protocol, such as http, you could use haproxy or nginx to redirect on layer 7, and that would allow you more fine-grained control (ie. url rewriting, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Depending what is behind the EIP you could use [local port SSH tunneling](http://blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html).

This does assume you have a linux box running behind the EIP. If you have an EIP alone and no EC2 behind it, I don't think you will be able to, besides, its seems like a strange problem to be trying to solve, what are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use nginx to handle the 301 redirect to the aws signin page.

Go to your nginx conf folder (in my case it's `/etc/nginx/sites-available` in which I create a symlink to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` for the enabled conf files).

Then add a redirect path:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name aws.example.com;
  return 301 https://myaccount.signin.aws.amazon.com/console;
}
```

If you are using nginx, you will most likely have additional server blocks (virtualhosts in apache terminology) to handle your zone apex (example.com) or however you have it setup. Make sure that you have one of them set to be your default server.

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name example.com;
  # rest of config ...
}
```

In Route 53, add an A record for `aws.example.com` and set the value to the same IP used for your zone apex.